# Shortened URL as custom URI scheme deep link

Tags: android, ios, react-native, deep-linking, react-native-deep-linking

**Question:**
There is a requirement to open an app's particular screen, based on a deep link in the react-native app.

I had implemented *demo:://app/...* as a custom scheme in *Andoridmanifest.xml* for Android and info.plist for iOS.

When I test it with *demo:://app/screen/2*, it deep-link to the app and opens the second screen of the app.
And this behavior is expected when the app receives *demo:://app/screen/2* from other apps.

The **problem** starts appearing when I try to test the app with *tinyurl.com/y4qygctx* instead of *demo:://app/screen/2*.

**Note** - *tinyurl.com/y4qygctx* is shortened form of *demo:://app/screen/2*.

Please enlighten solutions based on your experience.
Thank you in advance !!!

Comment: you have to declare deep-link scheme in manifest, thats all. use `demo://` scheme always or declare specific `tinyurl` URL (which isn't reliable, thats not yours domain)

Comment: Here tiny URL is just an example. shortened URL can be anything but it is short url for `demo://app/...`. what if someone use bit.ly url instead of `demo://app/...`??

Comment: `bit.ly` is just an url, it will be opened in app which supports that kind of links, so probably only web browser. and when browser send request for content it will get redirected link and will try to resolve it - how it will be done it depends on browser, some may try to look for a supporting app, some other may just show "can't resolve" hint. note that since Android 11 apps have very restricted access to check which apps are installed on device and what they are supporting/which privileges they have declared/granted

Comment: @AnkitKumar Did you find a solution to this? Using bitly it works fine for the app in iOS but not for Android it just opens in the browser.